# SQLite3 Python27 query hangs in Windows

Tags: windows, python-2.7, sqlite

A little bit of background.  This is a script designed to narrow down a large data set (3+GB files).  What I have is a series of SQL queries to create temporary tables for inserting/deleting from other tables.

Here is what the first few queries look like:

Query #1

```sql
create table clash as
select *
from
    StallConnected
group by Store, Stall, StartTime
having
    count(*) > 1;
```

Query #2

```sql
create table OverlappingStarts as
select A.*
from
    StallConnected as A
    join
    clash as B
    on
        A.Store = B.Store
        and
        A.Stall = B.Stall
        and
        A.StartTime = B.StartTime
    order by
        A.Store, A.Stall, A.StartTime;
```

Now on to the meat of the issue.  I'm executing these queries in sequence using a db connection in python's sqlite3 module on a **single** thread.  Here's the code:

```py
for i, val in enumerate(queries):
  print "Step " + str(i + 1) + " of " + steps
  db.executescript(val)
db.commit()
```

I know that `executescript()` will cause a `COMMIT` to happen before each statement is executed, but what happens is that it will perform the first query just fine, but the second query will simply hang.  No exceptions, nothing.

I know it can't possibly be the timeout happening since this is running on a single thread.  It doesn't throw an exception either (obviously, it just hangs).  I know it hangs because the db-journal file is only 2KB.

What I've tried:

- Committing after every statement
- Closing/reopening the connection
- Using `execute()` over `executescript()`
- Using a cursor object over directly calling `execute()` on the db connection

Any thoughts?  Am I doing anything inherently wrong?  Windows file locking issue that I don't know about?

**EDIT 1:** After running the script for the past hour I have found that some of the table has actually been populated.  What is the deal here?  Running my entire sql script inside DB Browser takes only about 30 seconds, and in python it takes upwards of 1 hour to populate one part of a table?

Side note:

```
>>> sqlite3.version
'2.6.0'
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.6.21'
>>>
```

Comment: That's a horribly old SQLite version. You should update Python, or execute the SQL in an external shell. Anyway, your biggest problem are the missing indexes. And show us the database schema.

Comment: Turns out it was a simple case of outdated sqlite.dll

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved!  Evidently my `sqlite.dll` library was horribly out of date and couldn't efficiently perform joins (something that didn't immediately jump out at me).

@CL thanks for the heads up!